# How to get friends' Facebook statuses using Javascript + FQL?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to build a Facebook app in Javascript that will let me retrieve a list of each friend's status by using FQL.  But it seems that no results are being returned from each FQL query.  Here is my code, cobbled together from various tutorial templates:

```
<html>
<title>Testing Facebook Javascript SDK</title>
<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        // init the FB JS SDK
        FB.init({
            appId      : 'MY_APP_ID', // App ID from the App Dashboard
        channelUrl: '//www.myurl.net/channel.html',
            status     : true, // check the login status upon init?
            cookie     : true, // set sessions cookies to allow your server to access the session?
            xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML tags on this page?
        });

    // Additional initialization code such as adding Event Listeners goes here
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
        if (response.status === 'connected'){
            showMyFriends();
            FB.api('/me/permissions',function(response){
                console.log(response);
            });
        } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized'){
            login();
        } else {
            login();
        }
    });


    };
    function login(){
        FB.login(function(response){
            if (response.authResponse){
                alert('login');
            } else {
                alert('cancelled'); 
            }
        },{scope:'read_stream'});

    }

    function showMyFriends(){
        FB.api('/me/friends',function(response){
            if(response.data){
                var length = response.data.length;
                for(var i=0;i<50;i++){
                    element=response.data[i];
                    getAFriendStatus(element.id);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function getAFriendStatus(friendUID){
        FB.api('/fql',{q:{"query1":"select message from status where uid="+friendUID}},
            function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        );
    }



  // Load the SDK's source Asynchronously
  // Note that the debug version is being actively developed and might 
  // contain some type checks that are overly strict. 
  // Please report such bugs using the bugs tool.
  (function(d, debug){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all" + (debug ? "/debug" : "") + ".js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document, /*debug*/ false));
</script>
</body>
```

When I check the console, all I get for each call to `getAFriendStatus()` is:

```
Object {data: Array[1]}
data: Array[1]
0: Object
fql_result_set: Array[0]
name: "query1"
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array[0]
__proto__: Object
```

Because the `fql_result_set` has a size of 0, I think there's a problem with my query.  I don't think it's a permissions problem, because the console output of `FB.api('/me/permissions')` is:

```
Object {data: Array[1], paging: Object}
data: Array[1]
0: Object
basic_info: 1
installed: 1
read_stream: 1
```

So I know that I have `read_stream` permission.  Why am I not getting the statuses with this query?

EDIT: I just tried the FQL query with

```
"select message from status where uid=me()"
```

and I got all of my recent status posts.  It seems that it's only a problem getting my friends' statuses?  Could this be due to their privacy settings?

Answer (score 0):

This works for me, I am using

```
select message from status where uid = XXX
```

which gives me the same result as using the Graph API

```
XXX?fields=statuses
```

Since you are only asking for "`read_stream`", you also need to add in permissions for your friends information. The additionaly permission you need to ask for is

```
friends_status
```

Without it, you just get the friend UID